# Can "everyone of an item" be possible?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> Everyone of apple is tasty.
>
> Anyone of banana you can take.

Is that grammatical?

Comment: Sorry guys, there were an error.

Comment: "Everyone" and "anyone" refer to people, you may be confusing them with "every one" and "any one" which refer to objects.

Comment: No. Every apple is tasty. You can take any banana.

Comment: @Peter -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: So if I give space, then the above sentences are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Everyone" and "anyone" refer to people, you may be confusing them with "every one" and "any one" which refer to objects.

Your sentences

> Everyone of apple is tasty.
>   Anyone of banana you can take.

are not grammatically correct.

The correct sentences are

> Every one of **the** apple**s** is tasty.
>
> Any one of **the** banana**s,** you can take.
>   *you can take any one of the bananas*
>   *you can take any of the bananas*

the definite article "the" is necessary since you are speaking about each of the fruits individually.